# Inferring types from an object shape definition

Tags: typescript

Consider the following approach for runtime type information with inference:

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCeAHApgHlgPmgbwLAChpoB6Y6AKwFcIAXaMaAWzACcBrZFgogE2VFbJoLZGB4B7AHYh40APo0kyAFxwA3AQC%20BAopTQAgpPgJ9AXjhLUYYxg34CAqNADyiGgEspYEOmjIADxpkSR4YIxMlLDxCaGApWhZKYBpxFgAKETEpGWgPSUlOVVgAShxtfArdJWgAZQALMHMcaABtNlVE-IBzAF1VCNMhAB9Xdy9JH1RBqOhNe2r9IZcAMwamtFh-IJCwusaULAtuaAAyFtaAaTzJaA54cRW4ehhYK97t4NDw4yHoAH5oNdVIUAG6cfpwd6fXY-SL6QFvS69VoAIgUSlRHxByHBLDmJ3O2Da13yd2QDyeW0gUORMO%20Y083l8M0OAKB0BxeN6-2K0MCXz2biZkxZv1miPeaPyhRYWLRGJQWM50DBnDmC3w8UktGgK3E4mgFmwACNWDiAO6WFCoSSURgmzgYdIlAA00DNAC9LYyJj50oUrUNUF1JN1nSUSpoXnEEjRNXohAAxA1G63IVbrG2Jx56g12HRauN58QAJjTpvNquQQasdodTpd0Zp2toCZqKbLaeWawOaBzT31ZYL%20CAA)

```
class Type<T> {
  // just a marker
  declare readonly _type: T;
}

type AnyType = Type<any>;

class Optional<T extends AnyType> {
  constructor(readonly inner: T) {}
}

type Shape = { [k: string]: AnyType | Optional<AnyType> };

type TypeOfShape<T extends Shape> = 
  & { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends AnyType ? K : never]: T[K] extends AnyType ? T[K]["_type"] : never }
  & { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends Optional<AnyType> ? K : never]?: T[K] extends Optional<AnyType> ? T[K]["inner"]["_type"] : never };

const foo = {bar: new Type<number>(), baz: new Optional(new Type<string>())} as const;

type Foo = TypeOfShape<typeof foo>;

const foo2 = {bar: new Type<number>()} as const;

type Foo2 = TypeOfShape<typeof foo2>;
```

As shown in the playground by hovering, `Foo` is inferred to

```
type Foo = {
    readonly bar: number;
} & {
    readonly baz?: string;
}
```

and Foo2 to:

```
type Foo2 = {
    readonly bar: number;
} & {}
```

On the surface, that's what I want, but would it looks ugly. Would it be possible to rewrite `TypeOfShape` somehow so that the optional and required subtypes are merged instead of intersected?

Comment: [Please restrict the post to asking a single question; if you have two questions you can make two posts.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741/511366)

Comment: Removed one question

Comment: Thanks!  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WYY0zW) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, please [edit] the example to show what the problem is.

Comment: @jcalz wow neat trick!

Comment: Does that mean you would accept an answer explaining that? Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: It means that it answers my question.

Comment: @jcalz Inspired by your solution, I added a utility type `export type Merge<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] };` that serves the purpose: `type TypeOfShape<T extends Shape> = Merge<...>;` also merges all intersections. However just figured out that sometimes (in nested types), `Merge` shows up.

Comment: Sure, although sometimes you might see `Merge<…>` in the type display if you give it its own name like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can often get the compiler to turn an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of object types like `{a: string} & {b?: number}` into a single object type like `{a: string; b?: number}` by applying an identity-like [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to it.

```
type Id<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] };
type AB = Id<{ a: string } & { b?: number }>;
/* type AB = {
    a: string;
    b?: number;
} */
```

Note that sometimes giving that operation a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) like `Id<T>` doesn't do what you want, because the type quick info via IntelliSense might use the name and the original intersection instead of the expanded type you were looking for:

```
type Hmm = {
  prop: Id<{ a: string } & { b?: number }>
}

/* type Hmm = {
    prop: Id<{
        a: string;
    } & {
        b?: number;
    }>;
} */ // that's not what we wanted
```

Instead I often use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to "copy" the type into a new type parameter which then has the identity mapped type inlined:

```
type Better = {
  prop: ({ a: string } & { b?: number } extends
    infer T ? { [K in keyof T]: T[K] } : never);
}
/* type Better = {
    prop: {
        a: string;
        b?: number;
    };
} */
```

---

Therefore, I'd render your `TypeOfShape<T>` as:

```
type TypeOfShape<T extends Shape> = (
  & { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends AnyType ? K : never]: 
       T[K] extends AnyType ? T[K]["_type"] : never }
  & { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends Optional<AnyType> ? K : never]?:
       T[K] extends Optional<AnyType> ? T[K]["inner"]["_type"] : never }
) extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never;
```

And we can verify it works as you like:

```
type Foo = TypeOfShape<typeof foo>;
/* type Foo = {
    readonly bar: number;
    readonly baz?: string;
} */
    
type Foo2 = TypeOfShape<typeof foo2>;
/* type Foo2 = {
    readonly bar: number;
} */
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCeAHApgHlgPmgbwLAChpoB6Y6AKwFcIAXaMaAWzACcBrZFgogE2VFbJoLZGB4B7AHYh40APo0kyAFxwA3AQC+BAopTQAgpPgJ9AXjhLUYYxg34CAqNADyiGgEspYEOmjIADxpkSR4YIxMlLDxCaGApWhZKYBpxFgAKETEpGWgPSUlOVVgAShxobXxK3SVoAGUACzBzcoBtNlVE-IBzAF1VCNMhAB9Xdy9JH1RBqIr7Gv0hlwAzRua0WH8gkLD6ppQsC3TuaAAyNoBpPMloDnhxZbh6GFhWi96t4NDw4yHoAH5oFdVIUAG6cfpwN4fQJfXYzfSA17vVoAIgUSlRHxByHBLAqJ3O2Ggb2ut2Q90em0gUPenx2MDcnm8vgRyCwgOB0DBEP+xWh9O+Y2Zk1Zv1mSOhaPyhRYWLRGJQWOgOLxBPwZVhDOuy040AAqgDLmS7g8DZD9QLNCrubjOPN8PFJLRoMtxOJoBZiQAjVg4gDulhQqEklEY3s4GHSJQANNBfQAvAPCiY+dKFQNDVBdSTdKMlMrWmlO2gOvRCACSPHQh2N+XJlLgkORH009nLhgAQp7oFXUMSwJ0aCwehUzuVvXzuWGI-jNHYCMQAFTQDsGbtek5EQfQHPdexEIiTkEz+1aaBL4g6fAdgASjEYPZiREQLHEiFUfYHQ5HubHRPjKdQ3DPV5y0a9l1XWp70fTdYhfN8P17atn0PNCdz3A9D2tIktzQwCTxAlgsKIed7GtS9rw7TtkBoYJ8TghD31UdJv13YdRxwicgNPOdBTCPD8l1fFNkBYlSXrU0qWbK0bR5FgSnIxcV2o2j6KfPDX2YnA8PQn8ehI-Dj2nIjDLbc9KIcKyOwAMXdHsllWfY0HLM03XEBd8Eg2z7MYw8sgkaRZF9FhCNnQyApyYKwATKdMIsq8rJLOh3IAJifeM-VtTMrGA2d8zHYsEhoMtajs8R0osRy1mDVzHjSzzvLK91Kp0+DhFEQLchCsKzyqC9iCAA)